# Should this be selection or projection

Tags: selection, projection

I have am learning relational algebra. I have a table,

```
Staff(name,salary,position)
```

Now a question states,

```
List all the managers with salary >25,000
```

Now the correct answer is,

```
selection position = manager ^ salary >25000(staff)
```

But I was thinking that it was,

```
projection position = manager ^ salary >25000(staff)
```

As we are selecting a particular attribute in the table and not selecting all the attributes. Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to "list all the managers", that means "select a number of rows".

You are not "selecting a particular attribute", but you are filtering on a particular attribute (to select a row).

Projection would be "list all the managers' names and salaries".

In terms of SQL:

- Selection is the WHERE clause
- Projection is the list of columns in the SELECT clause